# Displaying a graph (not charts) in an android app

Tags: android, graph, graph-layout

I want to display a small (n < 50) undirected [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29) (*not* a [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart)) in an Activity. I did a bit of research and it looks like their are a couple of libraries to display charts, but none to display real graphs. So it looks like I need to roll out my own solution. My very rough plan looks like this:

- create and in memory representation of the graph
- layout the graph nodes and edges so it looks nice
- write a view that implements pinch and zoom
- draw the graph

Are their *any* libraries I could use to help in some of these steps (maybe except the first one, this is really simple). Especially the "layout" part is something I would like to avoid. The "looks nice" requirement is mostly optional as long as the graph is displayed somehow readable. but since I'm part time perfectionist I would love to have it in ;)

Comment: Can you add a little description here about the differences you need between a chart and a graph?

Comment: You may refer to [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/Home.php), which is ope source for ideas on graph layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it eventually by using a WebView that displays a HTML page, that uses the [Dracula Graph Library](http://www.graphdracula.net/). I transfer the data to the WebView by a Java function that was called from Javascript (on page load) that encoded the data as JSON. Not fancy, but it worked!